# wordpress seo yoast change xml sitemap priority for taxonomy

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm using **wordpress seo yoast plugin** in to a web site.In the xml sitemap settings I enabled yoast plugin sitemap and it is working fine.In the admin panel there is the **taxonomy** named "stores". This is like categories. But i need to set it's priority **from 20% to 60%** in the store-sitemap.xml file.

[image]

I added following filter and it is not worked and not displaying to set the **priority** when adding or editing the stores.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_metabox_prio', 'move_yoast_metabox_down' );

function move_yoast_metabox_down( $priority ) {
    return 'high';
}
```

But this priority setting option can be view in the post types.
[image]

If anyone has solutions appreciate it.
Thank you